# Is a home router with 1Gbit ethernet likely to be the limiting factor to network performance in a house wired with Cat6?

Tags: networking, ethernet

We have wired parts of our house with Cat6 which is rated at 10 Gbps. However our 4-port modem/router supports only 1Gbps ethernet.

In theory that means it's a huge bottleneck - 10Gbps means you could (again in theory) have network-attached storage performance on a par with a local USB3 drive. But often theoretical speeds are unattainable in real life, is this one of them?

For practical purposes, is my router/modem likely to be a significant bottleneck for network-attached storage? We can assume all cabling is Cat6 and all network machines have 10Gbit network. Is adding a Cat6-rated hub in its place (with the hub connected to the modem) likely to make much difference?

Comment: Please understand, your network moves at the speed of the devices, not the media (provided that the media is capable of meeting/exceeding the devices speeds). So your router isn't the bottleneck, its all your devices from nics to switches to routers and APs. You have a 1Gbps network. upgrading to 10Gbps involves upgrading all those devices. Also note that most I/O devices on non-server systems won't support 10Gb/s. for instance, even at gigabit speeds in nics/switches, if you are reading or writing to an HDD, your I/O speeds aren't likely to use even full gigabit capacity. 10Gb/s = 1250MB/s.

Comment: I've said in the question *my cabling is Cat6 and my devices are 10Gbit* (at least the ones I care about). It makes a _big_ difference I think - it means I can use a NAS for network storage virtually without any performance drop-off compared to a local drive for instance

Comment: @Mr.Boy I misread the last paragraph and missed that all the devices were 10Gbit; For LAN, the only way you'd benefit from 1.25GB/s throughput is if running reading/writing to SSDs on the 10Gbit devices or reading/writing to NAS that's configured to first cache data received to RAM prior to writing to disk/writing to a cache SSD prior to writing to HDDs

Comment: _Cont'd_ @Mr.Boy For WAN, 10Gbit doesn't exist from an ISP _(we're at least a decade or more away from that, as it requires tens of billions in hardware upgrades from ISPs)_, unless aggregating multiple connections; however, you would benefit if running a 5G sim in a router _(many routers have SIM slots on the motherboard)_, else >1Gbit fiber would be required. With >1Gbit WAN, you'd require a commercial router, a DIY built router running a router OS _(Sophos UTM [software appliance], pfSense, etc.)_, or a custom solution _(such as a ClearFog from SolidRun)_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your devices are all connected to a 10 gigabit switch which in turn connects to the router it wont be a bottlenect, however if you are connecting all the devices to the router directly then yes, it will slow everything down - in fact you would likely be better off with a gigabit switch which will offload the processing of LAN lackets from the router.  Many SOHO routers bridge the ports in software and dont have enough CPU to do it well.

Answer (score 1):

It would be the bottleneck however I wouldn't say it's a significant one. The router is an easy appliance to upgrade unlike the wiring in your walls. Most premium consumer electronics are only using 1Gb NICs, even the newest ones are only using 2.5Gb NICS, so unless you're hosting enterprise level storage or inserting your own NICs. It will likely be unnoticeable for at least the next 3 years if not longer.

Comment: You missed the bit on the question "We can assume all cabling is Cat6 and all network machines have 10Gbit network."